# Looping in PhoneGap-NFC function

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I have a problem in a function PhoneGap-NFC plug-in Intel XDK.

```
function nova_pulseira(cli_nova_id) {
    nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(function (nfcEvent) {
        var tag = nfcEvent.tag;
        var = TagID nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id);

        if(TagID! == 0) {
            nova_pulseira_input(cli_nova_id, TagID);
        } else {
            myApp.alert( 'error in reading the bracelet.' 'Notice');
        }
    });
}
```

The **nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener** function is used for reading NFC TAG when occurs **nfcEvent**.
In the first reading it works normally, but when make the second reading, the **nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener** function is applied two times, the third reading, it is applied 3 times, and so on.
The only way I found to "stop" this function is using **location.reload();** but he returns to the Application home page, and the ideal would be to activate a subpage.
I would, somehow, that **nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener** function is disabled after applying the **nova_pulseira_input(cli_nova_id, TagID);** function.
PS: I've used
-> Return false;
-> $ .each (Nfc, function () {this.reset ();});
-> Intel.xdk.cache.clearAllCookies ();
-> $ .ajaxSetup ({Cache: false});

Thanks for the help of all ...

Comment: I recommend you make a simpler event handler that generates console.log() messages and prints the object information you receive. Avoid using an alert to debug the issue. Alerts can interfere with normal processing and cause difficult to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function inside a var and redefine it later:

```js
var tagHandler = function () {
        handlerOk();
 };
    
function handlerOk () {
  console.log("handlerOk()");
  tagHandler = function() {
   console.log("disabled..")
  };
}

function tag() {
    console.log("tag()");
    tagHandler();
}

tag();
tag();
```